# mysql/php variables in loops

Tags: php, mysql

I'm teaching myself PHP/Mysql and have come across a situation that is driving me crazy. Apologies if it is simple, but I just can't see it. I have bolded the few lines where I believe the issues lay.

I have a MySQL database. I use a foreach loop to iterate through entries in a table (up to 20) and build a div on the main page with the details for each item (pic, name etc), as such:

```
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY Category"); 
        $results = array();
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $results[] = $row;
        }
        $tempProduct="";

        foreach ($results as $row) {
            $v = $row['idMenu'];
            $x = 'Schk'.$v;                             
            **$var = 'output'.$v;**
            if ($tempProduct == $row['Category']) {
                echo "<div class=\"product\"><img src=\"images/Pics/".$row['img']."\" alt=\"".htmlspecialchars($row['Name'])."\" class=\"pngfix\" title=\"".$row['Description']."\" /><br /><label>".$row['Name']."</label><br /><label><a href=\"#Modify".$row['Name']."\">[+/- extras]</a></label><br />";
                **echo '<div id="'.$var.'" style="width:150px;">'.$$var.'<br /></div>';**
                echo '<a href="#x" class="overlay" id="Modify'.$row['Name'].'"></a>';

                echo '<div class="popup">';                         
                echo '<form method="post" action="" name="Creatform'.$v.'" id="Creatform'.$v.'">';
                echo '<h2>'.$row['Name'].'</h2><input type="submit" class="button2" value="OK" href="#close">';
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="Rid" id="Rid" value="'.$var.'">';
                echo '<img src="images/Pics/'.$row['img'].'" name="img"><br>';

                echo '<div id="divMain">';
                echo '<label class="Inc"><strong>Included:</strong></label><br><br>'.$$x.'<br>';
                echo '<hr class="Ingline">';
                echo '<label class="Inc"><strong>Extras:</strong></label><br><br>';
                echo '<h7>First:</h7><br>'.$Tchk.'<br>';
                echo '<h7>Second:</h7><br>'.$Uchk.'<br>';
                echo '<h7>Third:</h7><br>'.$Vchk.'<br>';
                echo '<h7>Fourth:</h7><br>'.$Wchk.'<br>';
                echo '<h7>Fifth:</h7><br>'.$Xchk.'<br>';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '</form>'; 
            }
        }
```

Each iteration contains code above for a popup modal window that has a list of checkboxes to allow extras to be added. This is also generated by a foreach loop from a db table:

```
        $Iresult = mysql_query("SELECT idExtras, Category, IDescription FROM Extras");
        while($Irow=mysql_fetch_assoc($Iresult))
        {
            if($Irow['Category'] == "First"){
                $Tchk .= '<div><input type="checkbox" name="chkIng[]" id="'.$Irow['idExtras'].'" value="'.$Irow['IDescription'].'"> '.$Irow['IDescription'].' </div>';
            }
            if($Irow['Category'] == "Second"){
                $Uchk .= '<div><input type="checkbox" name="chkIng[]" id="'.$Irow['idExtras'].'" value="'.$Irow['IDescription'].'"> '.$Irow['IDescription'].' </div>';
            }
            if($Irow['Category'] == "Third"){
                $Vchk .= '<div><input type="checkbox" name="chkIng[]" id="'.$Irow['idExtras'].'" value="'.$Irow['IDescription'].'"> '.$Irow['IDescription'].' </div>';
            }
            if($Irow['Category'] == "Fourth"){
                $Wchk .= '<div><input type="checkbox" name="chkIng[]" id="'.$Irow['idExtras'].'" value="'.$Irow['IDescription'].'"> '.$Irow['IDescription'].' </div>';
            }
            if($Irow['Category'] == "Fifth"){
                $Xchk .= '<div><input type="checkbox" name="chkIng[]" id="'.$Irow['idExtras'].'" value="'.$Irow['IDescription'].'"> '.$Irow['IDescription'].' </div>';
            }
        }
```

When you click the link and the modal pops up, you select additional extras and press the "go" button. The submit then refers to the following within the same page:

```
        if(isset($_POST['chkPIng'])){
            $output = $_POST['Rid'];

            if(!empty($_POST['chkPIng'])){  
                $Included = $_POST['chkPIng'];
                foreach ($Included as $val) {
                    $$output .= ''.$val;
                    $$output .= ', ';
                }
            }
            if(!empty($_POST['chkIng'])){   
                $extras = $_POST['chkIng'];
                foreach ($extras as $val) {
                    $$output .= '+ '.$val;
                    $$output .= ', ';
                }
            }
            **$Xtras=$$output;**
        }
```

The output of the function is supposed to display on screen under the particular item, in the div within the original listing:

```
echo '<div id="'.$var.'" style="width:150px;">'.$$var.'<br /></div>';
```

My issue is that when submitting the form the first time, all is good. However the function overwrites the output each time it is used, so the first time works well, second then overwrites the first result etc etc, and this changes the main page  so that any items that have extras will show the same extras as the last iteration. Also, only the div for the last item that had extras selected is visible, I need each to stay visible and populated with it's own extras. Is there a way I can do this and keep each output of the function specific to the item it was called for? I can't for the life of me see it, I know it has to do with the output variable.

Can anyone shed some light? Apologies for the length of this, happy to add info if needed. Please go easy, I'm just learning as I said. Thanks.

Comment: The mysql_* functions are deprecated.  You should learn mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: Thanks, I had started on this already, but I have been reading up on mysqli, I would like to finish this thing first before moving onto that.

Comment: Shot in the dark: Should it be `$Tchk = ` instead of `$Tchk .= `

Comment: Thanks for the response. As there are several checkboxes assigned to a category in the table, I am concatenating Tchk to account for them all.

Comment: I may be way off, but here's what it sounds like to me.  Each time you click the submit button you're refreshing the page.  That page refresh is causing only the last submission to appear on the new page.  Are you trying to store the information anywhere that I missed while skimming?  If not, you could either store it in `session` variables, hidden input elements on the page, or use AJAX on the submission so you're not refreshing the page each time you submit.  My apologies if I'm way off and dead wrong.  It's early, and I haven't had my coffee yet.

Comment: LOL, just had my first cup. Using Session variables has helped with one part of my issue. Now the divs for each item only update with their own extras, so thanks for that.